# Activty height does not match parent on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro

Tags: android, android-activity

I am trying to create an activity that will match the parent height. When I am testing the application on Pixel XL the application is fine, but when install on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro I have one part of the screen that it's not covered. This is the part above the camera, and it might be that my question is not only for this phone but I guess for all the others with the same design.

This is how it looks on pixel and it's ok:

[image]

And this is how it looks on Xiaomi Redmi Note 9 Pro:

[image]

This is my activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/main_screen_background"
tools:context=".activty.WelcomeActivity">

<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Toolbar if needed:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/main_screen_background"
android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/test_menu_language_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/about_dropdown_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_ikonki_potrosuvaci_02" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/language_dropdown_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="MK"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

What I want to achieve is to have covered also that black part and have the color from the activity, probably an easy thing but I am little rusty with android. I checked the other applications and they are covering that part.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So actually there are only two lines of code needed to be added in your v27/styles.xml:

```
<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
    shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

The first will cover that area and the second will set the color of the activity to that area. This is how my styles.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">
        shortEdges <!-- default, shortEdges, never -->
    </item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceLarge
    </item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/myPopupMenuTextAppearanceSmall
    </item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Finally I have applied this style to every activity that I have.